# Prove F[X]/p(x) contains all roots of p(x)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let p(X) be an irreducible polynomial in F[X], F a field. Prove or Disprove:
F[X]/(p(X)) contains all the roots of p(X).

I'm fairly certain the correct way to do this is to "Prove" it as opposed to "Disprove" but I'm having a really hard time getting started.

Comment: It is in general not true, find a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is false.

** Hint for a counter-example: **

Take $F=\mathbf Q$, $p(X)=X^3-2$ and consider the complex roots of this polynomial.

$$\mathbf Q[X](p(X))\simeq\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]2).$$

Does this field contain all the roots of $p(X)$?

Comment: This is the simplest example.

Comment: you forgot the line for $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p)$